# Подключение DLL matlab в Qt mingw cpp

Tags: c++, qt5, dll, mingw, matlab

Собираю приложение для работы с matlab-овскими функциями (чтение-запись .mat файлов), которое требует подключение его проприетарной библиотеки. Изначально подключил статические .lib файлы из [описания](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/mat-file-library-and-include-files.html), скопировав нужные файлы в директорию с проектом и указав их в файле.pro через директиву `LIBS += (путь) (флаг библиотеки)`. После сборки, каждый запуск приложения из qt мнгновенно заканчивался закрытием приложения, а debug не запускался. Запустив приложение не из qt, а из проводника, увидел ошибки и понял, что приложение почему-то не находит кучу matlab-овских библиотек dll, хотя путь до них прописан в системном PATH. После запуска windeployqt и копированием всех необходимых dll матлаба в папку с приложением, приложение наконец-то нормально запустилось.

Вопрос: почему приложение и qt не видит библиотеки dll, указанные в path? Пробовал в .pro добавлять строки типа `LIBS += $${PATH}`, но это ничем не помогло (т.е. если удалить некоторые dll из папки с проектом, они опять перестают видеться). Каким образом можно подключить эти dll, не копируя их в папку с проектом, и чтобы это работало на разных машинах с установленным матлабом? В гугл ходил, многие вопросы выглядят так, как будто поиск dll в PATH работает нормально.

qt5, win10x64

Comment: Для начала стоит проверить, что переменная окружения PATH содержит надлежащее значение при запуске приложения.

Comment: @user7860670 в переменных окружения в PATH путь указан, причем очень давно (т.е. много раз перезагружался после этого), смотрел через компьютер-дополнительные параметры системы. Можно каким-то еще образом узнать PATH на момент запуска приложения?

Comment: "дополнительные параметры системы" не обязательно показывает переменные окружения, с которыми запускается приложение. У запущенного процесса их можно посмотреть, например, в Process Explorer, на вкладке Environment. Или в самом приложении прочитать и распечатать в лог куда - нибудь

Comment: @user7860670 через process explorer видно, что у процесса PATH совпадает с системным PATH, т.е. указан нужный путь до матлабовских dll

Comment: А эти dll прилинкованы (т.е. есть в таблице импорта) или подгружаются вручную (посредством LoadLibrary)?